# checking for integer palindrome using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, palindrome

I'm trying, and failing, to check for whether or not a 5-digit integer is a palindrome or not using javascript. I have gotten the code to correctly check for 5-digit strings (not integers yet). That part should be relatively easy to figure out.

My main question: Am I doing the structure for using functions in javascript? If so, how can I get the function call to work properly? It just quits the program upon receiving the desired input.

Code is as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    var userInput;
                    var counter = 0;

                    function palindrome(userInput) {
                        var re = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/g;

                        userInput = userInput.toLowerCase().replace(re, '');
                        var len = userInput.length;

                        for (var i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
                            if (userInput[i] !== userInput[len - 1 - i]) {
                            return false;
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }

                    userInput = window.prompt("Please enter a 5-digit, numerical palindrome: ");
                    palindrome(userInput);

                    while (counter < 10){
                        if (userInput.length == 5){
                            if (pandindrome(userInput) == true){
                                document.write("The input is a palindrome!");
                            }
                            else if (pandindrome(userInput) == false){
                                document.write("The input is not a palindrome! Try again!");

                                userInput = window.prompt("Please enter a 5-digit, numerical palindrome: ");
                                palindrome(userInput);
                            }   
                        counter++;
                        }
                        else if (userInput.length != 5){
                            alert("The input you entered was not 5-digits! Please try again!");

                            userInput = window.prompt("Please enter a 5-digit, numerical palindrome: ");
                            palindrome(userInput);
                        }
                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: You don't do anything with the return value of the initial call to `palindrome` - and you should rename it to `isPalindrome`. Are you meant to be treating the input as a string? (As there is an algorithmic solution to checking if an integer is palindromic without converting it to a string).

Comment: *Update* Well I feel stupid! It turns out I had some spelling errors; that's what I get when I try to write code at 2:30 AM! I am still having some trouble checking to make sure it's an integer and not anything else. I can't seem to figure out the right syntax to exclude everything but numbers.

Comment: I get a very weird error! When I input 123456 or any other sequential number other than 5 digits long it crashes. What could be doing this?

Comment: Turns out the solution I found was causing the error! the isNan(num) function apparently does not like sequential input like 1234 or 7654. (noted!) I used the === checker instead; it was an easy swap. I kind of worked it out myself, but hanks for the pointers! If anyone is interested in what I cam up with, let me know and I'll post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code, everything works fine!

FIY, I set a variable isPalindrome to store the return value from the function palindrome. Then you can use it directly inside if statement, instead of compare to true.

```
var userInput;
var counter = 0;

function palindrome(userInput) {
  var re = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/g;

  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase().replace(re, "");
  var len = userInput.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
    if (userInput[i] !== userInput[len - 1 - i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

userInput = window.prompt("Please enter a 5-digit, numerical palindrome: ");
var isPalindrome = palindrome(userInput);

while (counter < 10) {
  if (userInput.length == 5) {
    if (isPalindrome) {
      document.write("The input is a palindrome!");
    } else {
      document.write("The input is not a palindrome! Try again!");

      userInput = window.prompt(
        "Please enter a 5-digit, numerical palindrome: "
      );
      isPalindrome = palindrome(userInput);
    }
    counter++;
  } else if (userInput.length != 5) {
    alert("The input you entered was not 5-digits! Please try again!");

    userInput = window.prompt("Please enter a 5-digit, numerical palindrome: ");
    isPalindrome = palindrome(userInput);
  }
}
```